# Multiple innerHTML functions

Tags: javascript, html, css, innerhtml

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function changeHistory(which) {
document.getElementById('maincontent').innerHTML="<iframe src='history.html' width='100%' height='100%' scrolling='auto'></iframe>";
}

function changeFigures(which) {
document.getElementById('maincontent').innerHTML="<iframe src='figures.html' width='100%' height='100%' scrolling='auto'></iframe>";
}
</script>


<li><a title="History" href="history.html" onclick="changeHistory(this); return false;">History</a></li>
<li><a title="Figures" href="figures.html" onclick="changeFigures(this); return false;">Figures</a></li>
```

Am I doing it right? How to NOT using different javascript methods for different link?

Is it possible to use variables in this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already passing the html-element to the function with this inline-function, which I think works nice in this way.

```
onclick="changeHistory(this);
```

Now if you alter the function like this, you could use the html-element you've just passed to get the actual url, which is the 'href'-attribute of that html-element.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function changeIframe(htmlElement) {
  document.getElementById('maincontent').innerHTML = "<iframe src='" + htmlElement.href + "' width='100%' height='100%' scrolling='auto'></iframe>";
}
</script>


<li><a title="History" href="history.html" onclick="changeIframe(this); return false;">History</a></li>
<li><a title="Figures" href="figures.html" onclick="changeIframe(this); return false;">Figures</a></li>
```

Have fun!

Comment: Hey I'm bit confused i'm not good in js so can u pls tell me which is 'maincontent' in this code, if its a function then why we use it???

Comment: @MBTheDeveloper Don't exactly what you mean, but maincontent is an html-element (div or something) with id='maincontent'.

Comment: No, but with javascript, if you are using getElementById, you are targetting an html-element. To answer amnbhrm (the topic-poster) his question, I don't have to know how his html-file look to give a right answer.

Answer (score 0):

yes it looks right, you could do this some thing like this which will pass the "href" from the link to the iframe's src.

```
function changeFrames(which) {

document.getElementById('maincontent').innerHTML="<iframe src='"+which.href+"' width='100%' height='100%' scrolling='auto'></iframe>";
}
```

Comment: Hey I'm bit confused i'm not good in js so can u pls tell me which is 'maincontent' in this code, if its a function then why we use it???

Comment: maincontent is a ID on a element this is where the iframe will apper in, eg `<div id="maincontent"></div>`

Comment: The fucntion looks for an element with the `id` called `'maincontent'`, if it finds it then look for a `HREF` from the calling link , and then display your iframe with a new browser page in it again referenced from the calling links `href`

Comment: BTW this does not work, since the single-quote and double-quote (around which.href) are not placed right.

Comment: @Mark-Knol ive rearranged the apostrophes thanks for the heads up :)